# Clearing a char from memory

Tags: c#, pointers, memory-management, unsafe

While i can easily get a pointer of a char from a string:

```
public static unsafe void Clear(this string s)
{
        fixed (char* charPtr = s)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                charPtr[i] = '\0';
        }
}
```

I can't seem to do the same for char: `fixed (char* c = ch)` does not work and gives me following error:

> You cannot use the fixed statement to take the adress of an already
>   fixed expression. Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'char*'

Is there anyway in C# that I can reach the pointer of the char and delete it (= '\0')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since characters are passed by value, you would need to pass the character argument in by reference:

```
public static unsafe void Clear(ref char s)
{
    fixed (char* n = &s)
    {
        *n = '\0';
    }
}
```

In this case, unsafe code is unnecessary; the above can be rewritten as simply:

```
public static void Clear(ref char s)
{
     s = '\0';
}
```

Note that since the first parameter of an extension method cannot have a `ref` modifier, the above cannot be used as an extension method.

---

Separately, your `Clear(string)` method relies on undefined behavior.  While unsafe semantics do allow to mutate a string, this can cause unexpected results.  Per the language specification (emphasis added):

> Modifying objects of managed type through fixed pointers can results in undefined behavior. For example, because strings are immutable, **it is the programmer’s responsibility to ensure that the characters referenced by a pointer to a fixed string are not modified.**

To illustrate the undefined behavior, consider the following code:

```
string d = "E";
string f = "E";
d.Clear();
Console.WriteLine(d);
Console.WriteLine(f);
Console.WriteLine("E");
```

Because of string interning, the all three strings are stored in the same memory location.  As a result, the code above prints three blank lines.

If the motivation for clearing the string is to clear sensitive data from memory, a supported approach is to use [`SecureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx).  Since the GC can relocate memory as needed, there is no assurance that clearing the variable's current address will remove all references to the string from memory.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and very constructive answer. I didn't know that extension method for char is sent by value.

I've put `if(string.IsInterned(s) == null)` in the beginning of the string cleansing method. I already use SecureStrings but I need to show data to the user sometimes, and make sure that the data is shown in the memory as short as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The `char` type is already mutable. So you can simply set its value to 0.

Assume you have the following `char`:

```
char c = 'a';
```

Simply set it to 0 like this:

```
c = '\0';
```

I am assuming here that you have direct access to the field/variable. Note that if you receive a `char` as a method argument or if you get it by invoking a property, then you get a copy of the original `char`. If you change that to 0 then you are mutating the copy of the original `char`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't know you that you send a copy by extension methods.